# Jquery ajax not showing php echo result

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I would like my ajax to display my echo from a php file after posting data. I am posting data into a database and when the post is successful I would like it to echo 'Complete' am going use whatever result I get from the post to determine what message I get from the processed php file. At the moment when I hit the submit it does insert the data but when I add an alert to see if the data on my ajax script reflects 'Complete', instead I get html code of the table I created and the word 'Complete' at the bottom. I would want Complete to be in the 'status parameter'.

Ajax Script

```
$.ajax({ 
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#frm').serialize(),
            url: "create_submitted.php?",
            cache:false,
            success: function (status) {
                        alert(status);
                        location.reload();
                }
            });
```

Php Script

```
session_start();
require_once("database.php");
require_once("class.php");
$reg = new SUBMITTED();
$reg->month = $_POST["month_s"];
$reg->year = rtrim($_POST["year_s"]);
$reg->month_year = $reg->year."-".date('m',strtotime($_POST["month_s"]))."-00";
$reg->user_fk = $_SESSION['franchise_code'];
$reg->create();
echo json_encode("Complete");
```

Comment: When you give `location.reload();`, it reloads the page. LoL.

Comment: comment `datatype: 'json'` then try..

Comment: And yeah, remove `datatype: 'json',`.

Comment: Semicolom is missing in the alert.

Comment: try this  header('Content-Type: application/json');
                $resp['data'] = 'Complete';
                echo json_encode($resp);  in ajax php file and in js use alert(status.data);

Comment: You might have error before `echo json_encode("Complete");`
Comment all other line and keep `echo json_encode("Complete");`
You will get the alert

Comment: What does the create function `create` of `SUBMITTED` do ?

Comment: @Loufylouf its a class that does the mysql posting that works

Comment: And does it print anything ? Like, I don't know, the HTML code of the table created ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `location.reload`, instead you can update only the required piece of html (such as a div or other element where the data will go).
You don't need to remove the `datatype:json` on the js like mentioned in the comments, but if you are expecting json to be returned, you need to set the corresponding header in php with:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

so that jQuery won't ignore the response with a different content type header which by default is "text/plain" or "text/html".

You can update the HTML with:

```
$("#targetElement").html("my html code");
```

or without jQuery:

```
document.querySelector("#targetElement").innerHtml("my html code");
```

Also, I highly recommend you do some validation on your php scripts, otherwise you are setting yourself up for XSS attacks if someone inserts a nasty `<script>` tag in the data submitted (you can avoid it by passing your received input on the php side by `htmlentities(__input_goes_here__)`

UPDATE:
Forgot to mention that you need to set the header in phpbefore anything gets printed to the page.

Also, if you check the success callback [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) you'll see that success can take 3 parameters:

```
Type: Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )
```

where:

- `data` is the data returned from the server
- `textStatus` is the status info returned from the server (404, 200 etc)
- `jqXHR` is the jquery object that made the call.

Currently you are only accepting one parameter but I recommend that you `console.log` all three so you can get a feel for what might be going wrong.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Am afraid that doesn't work I added this in my php file removed the location.reload and this time nothing was alerted

Comment: @TapuwaSimonMundeta you need to set the header on php before anything gets printed out otherwise you'll get the "headers already sent" header.
Will update the answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({ 
type: "POST",
data: $('#frm').serialize(),
url: "create_submitted.php?",
cache:false,
success: function (status) {
     alert(status);    
}});
```

You were reloading the page every time the script was successful because of `location.reload();`
Also, `datatype: 'json',` is not needed.